# Clearing floated list items

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having trouble clearing my list items that I've floated left As you can see from my jsFiddle the first list item is pushing the third item across messing up the layout. See my 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqHXP/)

```
<style>

.wrap {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul.team-members {
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul.team-members li {
    float:left;
    width:450px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

ul.team-members li img {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

ul.team-members li p {
    float:left;
    width:310px;
    margin:0;
}
</style>

    <section class="wrap">

        <h1>Our Team</h1>

        <div class="store">

            <h2>Monmouth</h2>

            <ul class="team-members">

                <li>
                    <img src="_/img/t-member.jpg">
                    <p><strong>Maureen</strong> - who is originally from Fife is our longest serving member of staff. Qualified to City & Guilds level in soft furnishings, Maureen is always keen to offer advice on projects, colour schemes, fabrics and trimmings. We have an 'Ask Maureen' option on our homepage where you can ask any soft furnishing or window treatment related question, the trickier the better as she loves a challenge!</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="_/img/t-member.jpg">
                    <p><strong>Rosyln</strong> - is known for her bubbly welcoming approach to all customers and is always keen to help with advice on the selection of suitable fabrics for your curtains, blinds or upholstery.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="_/img/t-member.jpg">
                    <p><strong>Clare</strong> - has a background in interior design and is very experienced and knowledgeable on fabric choices, tracks, poles and the full spectrum of soft furnishing and upholstery options.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="_/img/t-member.jpg">
                    <p><strong>Ann</strong> - Manages our team, our workrooms and arranges installation in conjunction with our.</p>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
</section>
```

Jeez I should know how to do this, mind has gone blank! Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `float:left` and use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`

```
ul.team-members li {
   display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;
    width:450px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EqHXP/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, very handy tip :) Not that I support ie7 these days but we'd need to use display: inline; zoom: 1; to as it dosn't support inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/EqHXP/5/)***

Hi now used to `:nth-of-type(odd)`

as like this

```
ul.team-members li:nth-of-type(odd){
clear:both;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/EqHXP/5/)***

Comment: So do you recommend this approach or use display:inline-block as above?

Comment: I've actually gone with this method and used selectivizr to target ie6-8. Ta

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul.team-members li {
float:left;
width:450px;
margin-bottom:40px;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Nope sorry all that does it clear the floats so nothing is floated left, resulting in just a stacked list of items.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`. Also don't forget to use `vertical-align: top;` to align the containers correctly.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EqHXP/3/